# Magento Layout update not loading

Tags: magento, magento-layout-xml

I am attempting to make a layout change that when a page in the backend loads that i can hide a few buttons, but i cannot seem to make my layout update trigger. following is my current code. Right now i am not concerned with the functionality of the block itself, only that my layout loads.

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mysite_Buttonhide>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mysite_Buttonhide>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <buttonhide>
                    <file>buttonhide.xml</file>
                </buttonhide>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <Buttonhide>
                <class>Mysite_Buttonhide_Block</class>
            </Buttonhide>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config
```

buttonhide.xml which is located in app->design->adminhtml->default->default->layout->buttonhide.xml

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="sales_order_edit"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Comment: All this looks correct. I presume you've refreshed cache?

Comment: Did you check if the module is actually active?

Comment: Yes the module is active, it is listed in the config/advanced listing of module outputs, and yes i have the cache disabled (i dumped the cache anyway though, just to be sure)

Comment: In buttonhide.xml you have it all wrapped in <layout> tag?

Comment: ...no? am i supposed to...

Comment: well now i feel dumb. thanks a bunch :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36346/discussion-between-nanos-and-marcinsdance)

Comment: Yes, you have to wrap it in a `<layout>`, and to start the file with `<?xml version="1.0"?>` for standard coherence.

Comment: Yes, it all should be wrapper in <?xml version="1.0"?><layout>... check how the other layout.xml files look in this directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the content of your button.xml file in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><layout>...</layout>
```

and you should be fine.